# Rails ajax form submit message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building my first rails application and am new to both ruby and rails. I am trying to render a submit message on a page after a form is submitted via ajax.

I have added to my form the :remote => true parameter. However I don't seem to be able to render a message after in my application. As a test I have set up a fresh rails app and generated a posts model and view etc with form using scaffolding.

I added the remote :remote => true to the generated form. It submits the data fine to the db. I have read I can just update the controller to include js with format.js, in this case updating posts_controller.rb func to

```
def new
  @post = Post.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.js
  end
end
```

A few tutorials have said you can then just add a new.js.erb or create.js.erb (not sure which it should be) in the views/posts folder and this should be executed but nothing happens other than the data being submitted.

I have also tried:

```
format.js { render :js => "alert('Hello Rails');" }
```

as a test.

I am using rails 3.1 and am at a loss to what I should try next

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there.  The submitted form is processed by the create action, not by new.  You've got the syntax right for handling html or js - you just need that in your create action, and a create.js.erb containing the js you want to render.

Your PostsController should have a create function along the lines of

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html 
      format.js 
    else
      format.html { render :action => 'new' }
      format.js   { render 'fail_create.js.erb' }
    end
  end
end
```

Create a file named create.js.erb (in the views directory for posts), containing

```
alert('Hello Rails');
```

and you should be good to go, for the success case.  Create a second file named fail_create.js.erb with whatever javascript you want to render in case of failure (e.g. when the submitted form data doesn't pass your model's validations).